# Как задать условие в WHILE для выхода из программы вводом любой буквы?

Tags: while, c++

Нужно сделать выход из программы, при вводе любой буквы (вместо нуля, как сейчас), а не чисел.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void main()
{
  int vozrast;
  int kol_mesicev;
  int kol_nedel;
  int kol_dnei;
  cout<< "Vvedite skolko vam let?\n";
  cin>> vozrast;
  while(vozrast!=0)
  {
    kol_mesicev=vozrast*12;
    cout<<"Vam:\n"<<kol_mesicev<<" mesicev ili\n";
    kol_nedel=kol_mesicev*4;
    cout<<kol_nedel<<" nedel ili\n";
    kol_dnei=vozrast*365;
    cout<<kol_dnei<<" dnei\n";
    cout<< "Vvedite novoe znachenie(Vixod-vvod 0)\n";
    cin>> vozrast;
  }
  cout<<"Vixod\n";
}
```

Comment: @CAYENNE7 Так С или С++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы  можете написать

```
while (cin.good() && vozrast != 0) {
   ...
   cin >> vozrast;
}
```

Вообще же, читайте [документацию](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iolibrary/)